# SyntaxError: missing : after property id in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new in angularJs, i have javascript which contains to load the applet.
that is working in javascript but when I'm putting same code in angularJs, that is not compiling, my script is not executing, for that i wrote a custom directive, but that is giving error **SyntaxError: missing : after property id**.

**Java Script:**

```
<div id="appletbox" class="photobox">
    <script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
    <script>
        var attributes = {
            id: "fingerCaptureApplet",
            width: 140,
            height: 140
        };
        var parameters = {
            jnlp_href: "fca/finger-capture-applet.jnlp"
        };
        deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.7');
    </script>
</div>
```

**Custom Directive Code:**

```
angular.module('some', ['ngRoute'])
.directive('fingerScanner', function() {
        return {
            var attributes = {
                id: "fingerCaptureApplet",
                width: 140,
                height: 140
            };
            var parameters = {
                jnlp_href: "fca/finger-capture-applet.jnlp"
            };
            deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.7');
        };
    });
```

using that directive is like below:

```
<div finger-scanner/>
```

please whether I'm doing right way or anything wrong.
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're returning an object. However, it seems like you're just trying to run the `deployJava` code.

To do this, [place your desired function in a `link` property](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom):

Replace:

```
return {
    var attributes = {
        id: "fingerCaptureApplet",
        width: 140,
        height: 140
    };
    var parameters = {
        jnlp_href: "fca/finger-capture-applet.jnlp"
    };
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.7');
};
```

With:

```
return {
    link: function(){
        var attributes = {
            id: "fingerCaptureApplet",
            width: 140,
            height: 140
        };
        var parameters = {
            jnlp_href: "fca/finger-capture-applet.jnlp"
        };
        deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.7');
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe your return is incorrect in your custom directive. You're returning an object but formatting the properties and methods like you would normal variables and functions. Remember that for objects, all properties are key value pairs (whether the value be another object, function, variable, etc.). Try reformatting your object like so:

```
angular.module('some', ['ngRoute'])
    .directive('fingerScanner', function() {
        return {
            attributes: {
                id: "fingerCaptureApplet",
                width: 140,
                height: 140
            },
            parameters: {
                jnlp_href: "fca/finger-capture-applet.jnlp"
            },
            appletResults: deployJava.runApplet(this.attributes, this.parameters, '1.7')
        };
    });
```